# share host folder with Vritual machine guest problem (centos 6.5)

Tags: kvm

I have centos 6.5 installed kvm. Then I created a virtual machine and tried to share the host folder (e.g. /mnt) with virtual machine using 9p_virtio. (follow this guide: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio)

However, in virt-manager. It shows the "Filesystem" menu is gray with this error "not supported for this hypervisor/libvirt combination".

I did some search online and some people said "the "Filesystem Passthrough" feature is still so new that it is not yet available for CentOS-6."

I am wondering if this is still a bug for centos 6.5 and if there is a way to alternatively solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way to access files would be for you to share the files on your host using CIFS or NFS and mount that share within your guest.

You would probably be best choosing NFS for Linux/Unix guests and CIFS for Windows guests.

There will probably be a small performance hit using this technique, but at least it will get you access to your files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. NFS is network-based, it will create huge traffic for the virtual network. I have cloud with 20 hosts, 80 virtual machines, each host has 0.5T data, then each host needs to access the data via the virtual network then the I/O should be very low.

Comment: If the performance issue is of concern, then your only options are to either:-

 - compile a later version of qemu/kvm/libvirt
 - purchase 20 subscriptions to RHEL7, which has just been released.
 - wait a few weeks/months and see what CentOS 7 brings.